# Stress testing a 64bit CPU with 32bit software (mprime)

Tags: 32-vs-64-bit, stress-test

When I stress test a CPU there are three things I'm looking for:

- Power consumption at peak load (can the PSU handle this CPU?)
- Heat disipation under heavy load (is it well cooled?)
- Reliability and stability under heavy load for a prolonged period of time

I believe Prime95 (mprime) takes care of all three points and then some.

If I run the 32bit binary of mprime in a 64bit CPU, will the test be as effective?

Is it possible that there is a problem with the CPU that mprime will only detect if I'm running the 64 bit binary?

Comment: Define "good idea".  As you suspect you won't use the full memory resources, without specifics and even with them, you still stress the CPU enough to determine the performance at least with the software you used

Comment: @ramhound the 'full memory resources' part would depend on whether I have more memory than what's usable for a 32bit OS or not, right? Anyway, I'm not concerned about stress testing the memory modules in this case, only the CPU. I'm not sure what kind of specifics I could provide... Do you mean CPU make/model and other hardware details?

Comment: If you are stress testing, a CPU that is at 100% usage, is a CPU that is at 100% usage.  You could be using 100 MB but still consuming all your CPU cycles.

Comment: @ramhound Sure, but is it possible that there may be a flaw in the CPU that goes undetected because I'm testing it with 32bit software? Is the instruction set the same regardless of the mode?

Comment: No; it is not the same but detecting that type of flaw isn't the point of stress test

Comment: Thanks @ramhound. I've edited my question to be more specific and to the point.

Comment: So run a 32-bit and 64-bit version of Prine95 and compare the results you won't see any difference.